# Installing Findbugs plugin successful but not working?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I install the findbugs successfully, but when I run it , nothing happen, even I use the obvious wrong code, it still does not respond, is there similar problem like mine?

Comment: This question isn't related to programming itself. You may get better help if you post it to Super User.

Comment: @Jieyu Zhang Did you try it via `build.gradle`

Comment: Have you tried to switch to FindBugs perspective?